# How to parse a .docx file which contains Math Equation using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, docx, mammoth

To be brief, I'm trying to parse some `.docx` word files which have **Math equations** inside and that's where the problem begins!

I want to use Node.js to parse the whole document including all texts, images, and those Math Equations, **no matter if I parse them as an image or a JS object**.

I tried [Mammoth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth) and some other JS packages but unfortunately, none of them support Math Equations.

I wonder if you have any alternative solutions. Thank you